# Warnings when passing a fixed size array to a function as a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a fixed size array (which will be always of the same size) containing bytes. Here is the code:

```
static void foo(uint8_t *arr_ptr);

void main()
{
    uint8_t arr[4];
    foo(&arr);
}

static void foo(uint8_t *arr_ptr)
{
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        arr_ptr[i]=1; // Set to one just to make it simpler
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a fixed size array at main as a buffer, and modify its content every time foo is called. It works as it should, but it gives some warnings and info's that makes me think something is not correctly stated.

> At `static void foo(uint8_t *arr_ptr);`: INFO: expected 'uint8_t*{aka
>   unsigned char *}' but argument is of type 'uint8_t(*)[4]{aka unsigned
>   char (*)[4]}'
>
> At `foo(&arr)`: WARNING: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type

Digging a bit at some other posts, I've seen that maybe a solution could be to declare it as `(*arr)[4]`, which may have sense, but applying them makes the code work different. I'm pretty sure I'm making my mind a mess with this pointer declaration and argument passing, so I'd appreciate if someone can help me clarify these concepts.

Comment: Don't pass the address of the array, an array is already (decays into)  a pointer when passed to a function: `foo(&arr);` --> `foo(arr);`

Comment: `&arr` is a pointer to the array itself, it has the type `uint8_t (*)[4]`. You want to pass a pointer to the first element, which is `&arr[0]`, or plain `arr` as that will decay to a pointer to the first element. That pointer will have the expected type of `uint8_t *`.

Comment: Thank you @KeineLust and@some-programmer-dude, that fixed the warnings. Anyway, that means that passing an array as it is to a function will always pass it as a pointer? So modifying it will modify it in main too...

Comment: @user11527039 yep!

Comment: Your current function already *is* modifying the contents of the array. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is because the passed pointer has another type.

Arrays decay to pointers:

```
int arr[10];

foo(arr); /* <- array decals to the pointer to int. */
foo(&arr); /* <- array decals to the pointer to array of 10 ints. */
```

Both pointers reference the same object in the memory but have different types - hence the warning.